# Github Action on NET.Framework project fails

Tags: github-actions, .net-framework-version

I am trying to implement github actions on a .NET Framework project (v4.7.2).
Everything works until the Build step, where some references are missing. Those references haven`t been added on the project using nuGet. They are local references that were added from other directories.

This is my code:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: mySolution.CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]


jobs:
  Build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: windows-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Setup MSBuild.exe
        uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2
        
      - name: Setup NuGet
        uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5
      
      - name: Restore nuGet packages
        run: nuget restore mySolution.sln 

      - name: Run MSBuild
        run: msbuild mySolution.sln /t:Clean,Build /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:Configuration=R2020
```

So, my question is how to find these references? (assuming that is the problem) any other suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Are those directories part of you repo?

Comment: Nop, that was the problem. I was adding them into a folder that haven`t been pushed to the repo. I am really new with this. Thanks!

Comment: I added this as reply. If iy solved your issue please mark it as answer and upvote if it helped you.

Comment: GitHub Actions uses another machine to clone your repo and execute all the steps, so if you don't have everything in that repo (or depend on something that can be acquired easily like NuGet) errors like that are expected. Keep that in mind and you will figure out what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be sure that files which are references by your project are available on build agent. So if you didn't add them to the repo please add them or make them available on build agent in another way.